# Calculate angle of line with negative slope

Tags: ruby, math, trigonometry

I'm creating a map, and calculating the angle of the lines to determine the orientation of a road (NSEW).

Below is the formula I'm using to calculate the angle of a line:

`Math.tan(slope) / (Math::PI/180)`

This works until the slope of my line is negative. How can I properly calculate the angle of a line with negative slope?

**Update** To calculate the angle of the line, I am now using

```
Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x) / (Math::PI/180)
```

The issue seems to stem from which points I select the line starts at/ends at. Depending which one I take, some are correct, some aren't, and vise versa. Here's an image of the map I create:

[image]

I'm only trying to calculate the angle of lines that intersect with the bounding box. One of the points is always where the line intersects with the bounding box, the other point is always just after that.

My origin (0,0) is at the top left.

Comment: Does the language you're programming in have a `Math.atan2(y, x)` function? That will give you the correct value in all four quadrants.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it does. I'm using Ruby. Would `y = (y1 - y2)` and `x = (x1-x2)`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton so `(Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x) / (Math::PI/180))` - I don't seem to be getting the correct angle. Yes on ` E=0, N=90, W=180, S=270`

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's correct, my origin (0,0) is at top left.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Does y1 always need to be the end of the line, or the opposite?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Still can't get this right. The issue seems to stem from which points I select the line starts at/ends at. Depending which one I take, some are correct, some aren't, and vise versa. Here's an image of the map I create http://imgur.com/e28QgH9  I'm only trying to calculate the angle of lines that intersect with the bounding box. One of the points is always where the line intersects with the bounding box, the other point is always just after that.

Comment: You just need to adjust the angle depending on which bounding line you are measuring from. (I incorporated information from the comments into your answer, please feel free to make further edits to it however you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following. Keep in mind this is an inverted axis where the origin (0, 0) is in the top left.

```
def angle(point1, point2)
  return 90 if vertical?(point1, point2)
  return 0 if horizontal?(point1, point2)
  point1, point2 = [point1, point2].sort_by(&:x)
  delta_x = point1.x - point2.x
  delta_y = point1.y - point2.y

  if point1.y > point2.y # inverted axis/origin
    Geometry.to_degrees(Math.atan(delta_y / delta_x)).abs
  else
    # Add 90 degrees when angle is in 3rd quadrant
    Geometry.to_degrees(Math.atan(delta_x / delta_y)).abs + 90
  end
end
```